# How to create deep-clone of DYNAMIC List?

Tags: c#, list, dynamic, deep-copy

I have a `List<dynamic>` and I need to create clone of that. I've tried thousand way to solve it, you are the last hope.

Code looks like this:

```
public class Basic
{
    public int Start { get; set; }
    public int Leng { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class MyObj
{
    public Basic Basic { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
public class MyObj1
{
    public Basic Basic { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
}
public class MyObj2
{
    public Basic Basic { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
public class MyObj3
{
    public Basic Basic { get; set; }
    public decimal Value { get; set; }
}
```

All this (`MyObj`, `MyObj1`, `MyObj2`, `MyObj3`) objects are in my `List<dynamic> list`

I need to create deep clone of `List<dynamic> list`.

Comment: Have you tried serialising with JSON or something?

Comment: yes, but no result...

Comment: well, to be honest, I found the way i can clone it, but again I've met face to face to the problem. using "foreach" I can take each object from list and cast to real object. `foreach (var r in list) { var myObj = r as MyObj1; (for examlpe) (.......) }` But the problem is that I can get obj1 class name (string). I need whole class to cast object in it. `var myObj = r as Type.GetType("MyObj1");` <- not working and I have no clue what to do ...